# Two one-way tickets from Sweden to Mexico via the US

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, proof-of-onward-travel, mexican-citizens

I am considering booking two one-way tickets to travel from Sweden to Mexico. I have both Mexican and Swedish citizenship and passports and a B1/B2 US visa valid until 2 years from now in the Mexican passport. I will be travelling on the B1/B2 visa to the US.

- The first ticket would be from Sweden to the US via Airline A.
- The second ticket would be from the US to Mexico via Airline B the next day (booked separately).

1) Are there any rules that I might not be aware of preventing this?

2) Am I likely to be refused entry to the US?

Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to prove the non-existence of something but no and no.

Comment: You appear to have all the documents you should need. Do you have some reason to think there might be a problem?

Comment: Mostly, that I'll be denied entry with two separate bookings.

Comment: I am not sure what the hesitation is; you have a valid confirmation on a flight exiting the US; and you cannot be denied entry into Sweden or Mexico due to your citizenship; and you have a valid visa to the US. I say relax and enjoy your trip!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the comments. I will try and write back if I succeeded or not :D
The hesitation is that one as a Mexican constantly hears that US officers are likely to turn people around for just about any reason. This perception is probably erroneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, wou will be admitted, if not for 6 months, then at least for the time needed to catch the connecting flight.
2. No, with a visa you're not even required to hold a return/onward ticket. Even if you were to enter visa-free as a Swedish citizen, I myself (being Swedish and a lone young male, i.e. a high-risk traveller) have never been asked to show a return flight confirmation (check-in staff in Sweden, however, would check the electronic ticket record, but again none of this matters seeing as you have a visa)

Comment: The return/onward ticket must in any event be to a destination outside North America, with an exception that might apply to Alejandro but might not.  So it's just as well that he has a visa.

Comment: @phoog As a Mexican citizen, he can legally reside in Mexico without further ado, so it would work even without a visa

Comment: The traveler has to be a resident of the destination country, not be able to become one.  See https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2.

Comment: @phoog Double-checked with the CBP - either legal residency or citizenship of the destination is required.

Comment: @phoog this is the perfect example of details that cause me to hesitate. Although I hope in most cases the officer will use common sense, there seems to be always room for problems :P

From what I understood, I'm on the safe side since I have a valid visa, not VWP. And I _am_ a Mexican citizen. It doesn't make sense that I would need to go anywhere else for the US's sake.

Comment: Crazydre: that may be their policy, but it's not what the regulations say.  Policies can change more easily than regulations, and have less legal weight in court (not that a VWP refusal has much chance of ending up in court).  @Alejandro: the requirement applies only to the VWP, so it really doesn't matter in your case.

Comment: I suspect (but do not know) that the reason that US authorities have not asked you to show return tickets is that the airline has already provided advance passenger information confirming that you have them, and that get pulled up when they scan your passport.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Why do they then ask how long I'm staying for, if it's stated in their records anyway?